# Личные имена

Tags: имена-собственные

У меня сакральное (сакраментальное?) отношение к имени человека. Это слово живет с человеком всю его жизнь.Не очень верю в разные придумки о том, что в имени содержится характеристика или даже судьба человека, но считаю, что к имени надо относиться бережно. Между тем нередко встречался со случаями, когда  иностранные имена в общении заменяли на русские, хотя бы немного напоминавшие по звучанию иностранные аналоги. Так, Жана или Джона называли Иваном, Саркиса - Сергеем, Майкла - Михаилом и т.п.  Я тоже как-то назвал одного из наших форумчан Борисом, так как его ник был обозначен иностранным словом на букву "б". Он, правда, немного обиделся на меня за это, но, по-моему, не сильно. Однако речь сейчас не о нем, а о том, как наши уважаемые форумчане относятся к такой практике замены имен, которая, насколько мне известно, держится в России. О других странах не слышал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, в разных странах к этому разное отношение. Например, при получении гражданства Исландии вероятно придется от фамилии. Хотя я не уверен на 100%. Если получать гражданство в странах центральной Европы, то имя тоже будет заменено на аналогичное, например, [см. здесь](http://www.f-turizm.narod.ru/tours/8.htm). Так что замена имен является вполне распространенной практикой и до некоторой степени позволяет сохранить культурную целостность.

Касательно замен Майкл - Михаил тут все проще. Дело в том, что в России пишут на кириллице. И примерно как пишем, так и произносим. А за бугром пишут на латинице. И произносят каждый кто как может. Немцы - Михаэль, англичане - Майкл. Но имя-то по сути одно. Т.е. это скорее вариации на тему одного и того же. К тому же и в быту многие называют своих близких не по именам, а по сокращенным их вариантам. Например, не Елизавета, а просто Лиза.

Так что однозначного ответа нет. Самый правильный подход - спросить у самого человека, как бы он хотел, чтобы Вы его называли. Тогда точно никаких поводов для обид не будет =)

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, не очень понимаю, о чем речь. Ну была традиция называть Лафонтена  Ванюшей, а Руссо - ещё и Иван-Яковом. Но уж наверное не потому, что "Наше всё" не знало французского. 
Я стараюсь называть человека с такими именами как можно ближе к оригиналу, насколько это русская фонетика позволяет. Но если Мойша хочет называться Мишей - так со всем нашим уважением, пусть будет Мишей.

Хуже другое. Когда Ханса-Христиана мы называем Гансом ("ганс" - гусь). Или того лучше: Анри IV - Генрихом.

Comment: Вот именно! Главное - уважение. Хотя, боюсь, что приучиться к Хайнрих Хайне будет трудновато...  

Но все же не очень понятно, почему сам человек жаждет переименования. В этом есть какая-то неуверенность, комплекс. Мы одно время жили в русском городе, в классе у сына был Максуд, он требовал, чтобы его звали Максимом. Наверное, чувствовал себя слишком противопоставленным основной массе. У нас же в республике эта практика, насколько я замечаю, практически пропала.

Comment: Причины-то есть. И самые разные. 
Китайца вон как ни назови - все равно неправильно будет. Так уж пусть будет Максимом, а не Сунь Хуньвынь. 
Или вот монгольский космонавт Майдаржийн Ганзориг по рождению носил имя Ганхуяг (имя у монголов идет после "отчества") - в переводе что-то типа "железный панцирь". По просьбе "русских товарищей" переименовали, подобрав синоним "зориг".
Аналочно -  с болгарином Георгием КакАловым, ставшим Ивановым.
И это только одна тема, причин, как сказал, много больше.

Comment: Ну, это крайности. Имя "Максуд" вполне приличное. Ясно, что он просто хотел быть "как все".

Answer (score 1):

Я - отрицательно. У нас раньше была практика татарские имена "переделывать" на русские. Вроде как мы, русские, иначе их не поймем, не запомним. Зачем это? Многие татарские имена очень красивые, например, Ляйсан, Миляуша и т.п.

Сейчас в нашем микрорайоне живет много приезжих из СНГ, из ср. Азии . И учителя всех детей называют правильно, на родном им языке. Ралина, Хошаваз, Фарахноз, Муслехиддин. (кстати, догадайтесь, кто из них мальчики, а кто - девочки. То же об имени Адель).  Единственно Муслехиддина зовут сокращенно Муследдин (я, по-крайней мере). Ну, дети, конечно, дразнятся "Муслик - суслик", но на то они и дети. Кстати, хороший парень, неравнодушный, хотя и трудно ему с русским языком.

Comment: Полностью согласна! У нас в Крыму тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что все перечисленные Вами имена римского (Сергий), еврейского (Иоанн) или славянского (Борис — Борислав) происхождения. Таким образом, переделкой являются как раз имена Жан, Джон и т.д. Поэтому, мне кажется, что нет никакой ошибки или нарушения высших законов в том, чтобы, например, Джозефа назвать Иосифом, Пола — Павлом, а Мэри — Марией. Это ведь одни и те же имена одних и тех же святых.

Comment: С Борисом - не все так просто. Вряд ли от "Борислав". Скорое всего это производное от Богорис, так звали первого известного носителя имени - царя Бориса Болгарского. Истоки же "Богориса" надо искать в тюркских, хотя возможно - с греческим окончанием.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. А то мне попадалось только, что, мол, Борис — это сокращение от Борислава.

Comment: Да, это распространенная версия. Но она весьма и весьма сомнительна.
Заодно - о ещё одной распространённой ошибке. Владимир ни к "миру", ни к "мiру", ни даже к "мvру" не имеет никакого отношения. Исторически там ять: -мhр, это морф со значением "великий".